# Template string replace in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace, eval

I'm trying to build a system where I can create a file based in a template.
The template is stored in DB and I populate the template with data sent from a form.

I've tried doing it this way but I can't get to use the array. It always gives me error.

```
<?php

$string = "test";
$text = "This is a text for testing";

$rplc_string = '{$string}';
$rplc_text = '{$text}';

$tpl = '<html><head><title>{$string}</title></head><body><h1>{$string}</h1><p>{$text}</p><ul><?php foreach($array as $key => $value): ?><li><?php echo $key; ?></li><?php endforeach; ?></ul></body></html>';

$tpl = preg_replace($rplc_string, $string, $tpl);
$tpl = preg_replace($rplc_text, $text, $tpl);

$array = array( 'one' => '1', 'two' => '2', 'three' => '3' );

ob_start();
eval('?>' . $tpl);
$output = ob_get_clean();

echo $output;

?>
```

Is there better way of doing this?

Comment: The bigger question is, why reinvent the wheel?  There are any number of robust templating systems out there, that will likely serve you better than something you have hacked together.  They would also provide a good opportunity to learn how such templating systems might be designed. Using `eval()` for starters is a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: @MikeBrant This is not a templating system. What I'm trying to do is the same you do when using a e-mail template which will be populate with data from user, just like you would replace $to_user by user name and $to_email by user email.

Comment: there are a number email templating libraries/engines as well that don't rely on eval. you are basically asking for someone to hijack your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace out double quotes with single quotes when you are defining $tpl

also the first arg of preg_replace needs to be a regular expression:

```
<?php

$string = 'test';
$text = 'This is a text for testing';

$rplc_string = '/{\$string}/';
$rplc_text = '/{\$text}/';


$tpl = '<html><head><title>{$string}</title></head><body><h1>{$string}</h1><p>{$text}</p><ul><?php foreach($array as $key => $value): ?><li><?php echo $key; ?></li><?php endforeach; ?></ul></body></html>';

$array = array( 'one' => '1', 'two' => '2', 'three' => '3' );

$tpl = preg_replace($rplc_string, $string, $tpl);
$tpl = preg_replace($rplc_text, $text, $tpl);

ob_start();
eval('?>' . $tpl);
$output = ob_get_clean();

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: I've edited this to fix the problem with preg_replace

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code. The first is that you believe that a variable will be interpreted between single quotes. It's false. A variable is only interpreted between double quotes or using the heredoc syntax.

The second error is a syntax error too. When you write a regex pattern you need to add delimiters. But since you have forget them, the curly brackets are seen as pattern delimiters instead of literal characters.

Comment: It works. The only problem is the array. My goal is to pass the array to the eval but I'm failing to do that. This is just a test code to get where I need and implement it in the real code.

Comment: @user3718566: Why are you asking for help if you know what is the problem? To be clear your code is bad formed and has no sense. You need to re-think your approach from the begining.

Comment: Because I think that there's a better way of doing this, simply I'm not getting there and that's why I'm asking for help, a little light at the end of the tunnel.

Comment: @user3718566: If you want more help, please post what you expect with your example string.

Comment: The goal is to populate $string and $text with data from the form and use array, which is data pulled from DB, in the template to create a new file with the data inserted.